# Java DateTimeFormatter fraction pattern?

Tags: java, datetime

Is there a pattern equivalent to the .appendFraction method for DateTimeFormatter?  This is what I want, but without having to include the .appendFraction() and surrounding .optional methods.

```
   DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern( "[yyyy[-][ ]MM[-][ ]dd]['T'][' '][HH:mm[:][.]ss]" )
            .optionalStart()
            .appendFraction( ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND , 1 , 6 , true )
            .optionalEnd()
            .appendPattern( "[Z][X]")
            .toFormatter();
```

I'd like something like this:

```
.appendPattern( "[yyyy[-][/]MM[-][/]dd['T'][ ]HH:mm[:][.]ss[.][SSSSSS][Z][X]]")
```

But the pattern above expects 6 micro second digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ""wonderful"" hack like this one to be able to parse your variable fraction:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[yyyy[-][ ]MM[-][ ]dd]['T'][' '][HH:mm[:][.]ss][.][SSSSSS][SSSSS][SSSS][SSS][SS][S][Z][X]");
```

Comment: The pattern above does work for parsing.  Thanks wargre.  I hope someone has a "prettier" solution though!   :-)

Comment: I’m pretty convinced that there is nothing better. Personally I’d stick to `appendFraction`; it may be wordy, but it’s clear to read and free from hacks, to me that would count more.